# Trunc/empty photo fids by FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get all photo fids albums.

For example, I have albums and my friends of course have albums.

I can get album fids by:

```
SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner IN (...)
```

It worked. Now I want get photo fid this albums:

```
SELECT object_id from photo WHERE album_object_id IN (albumFid1,albumFid2)
```

Now I can get errors (empty or truncate data). If I use only one param with IN(), it's all ok. I see photo fids. But if I use several album fids, I starting get incorrect data. No matter who is albums owner.

I try simple test: get all photo fids of all my albums:

```
fql?q={"albums":"SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner = me()", "photos":"SELECT object_id from photo WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #albums)"}
```

It worked. Also worked if I use any my friend. But if I use several users - and album fids of different users, now get magic results.

I open bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/445214712163793. But not have any response. In bug I use situation with two albums (me and my friend). I get diff results then use diff album fids order with IN().

Interested, that two weeks ago all worked correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find only one solution: use FQL multi query. Each query - one user albums.